# Why does the %m construct does not work for emacs-lisp-mode?

Tags: major-mode, mode-line, mode-line-format

I have the following modeline configuration :

```
  (setq-default
   mode-line-format
   '((:eval
      (me/simple-mode-line-render
       ;; Left.
       (quote (" "
           mode-line-mule-info
           mode-line-client
           mode-line-modified
           mode-line-remote
           "  "
           (:eval (when (bound-and-true-p meow-mode) (propertize (meow-indicator) 'face 'bold)))
           "  "
           "L%l"))
       ;; Right.
       (quote (
           (vc-mode vc-mode)
           "   "
           "%b [%m] "))))))
```

As you can see in the image below, the major is correctly printed for Org and Dired (and it works fine for every other major mode I have tested).

[image: functional modeline]

However the only mode which is not printed correctly is emacs-lisp-mode.

[image: non functional modeline]

Do you have any idea of why it does not work only for this mode?

EDIT

Here is the code for function me/simple-mode-line-render. This function allows us to align elements in the modeline to right or to the left of the modeline.

```
  (defun me/simple-mode-line-render (left right)
    "Return a string of `window-width' length.  Containing LEFT, and
  RIGHT aligned respectively."
    (let ((available-width
       (- (window-total-width)
          (+ (length (format-mode-line left))
         (length (format-mode-line right))))))
      (append left
          (list (format (format "%%%ds" available-width) ""))
          right)))
```

Using emacs -q and load just the two blocks of code presented above leads to the same result as you can see below.
[image: emacs -q does not work]

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What is `me/simple-mode-line-render`? Do you have the same issue when running `emacs -Q` with the above code?

Comment: @amitp Thanks for you comment, I have updated the OP accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I kept removing things from your mode line to see what would happen, and `(setq-default mode-line-format "[%m]")` does the same thing. No mode displayed in Emacs Lisp mode, with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: I have tried that too (evaluating `(setq-default mode-line-format "[%m]")` with `emacs -q`) and I get the same result. Do you think I should send a buf report ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was answered by Eli Zaretskii on the Emacs mailing list :

> %m in mode-line-format is obsolete; use the variable mode-name
> instead.
> (The technical reason behind what you see is that %m displays the mode
> name only if the value of mode-name is a string, which in this case it
> isn't.)

So I have replaced %m by mode-name and everything works as expected :

```
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 '((:eval
    (me/simple-mode-line-render
     ;; Left.
     (quote (" "
         mode-line-mule-info
         mode-line-client
         mode-line-modified
         mode-line-remote
         "  "
         (:eval (when (bound-and-true-p meow-mode) (propertize (meow-indicator) 'face 'bold)))
         "  "
         "L%l"))
     ;; Right.
     (quote (
         (vc-mode vc-mode)
         "   "
         "%b "
         "["mode-name"] "))))))
```